Can't join two meshes using Boolean Union or "Ctrl Shift Num +"
I had a single holistic object (Cabin), then selected some faces (for windows), and separate them into a new separate object (Windows). Now I want to get a single holistic object as before (all vertices must be connected). I tried two ways:

I enabled "Mesh: Edit Mesh Tools", then seletced both objects and press "Ctrl Shift Num+", but I get a strange result (this way works for me in case of "simple" meshes).

I applied the Boolean modifier with Union mode (and Exact), but again get the wrong result (it works for simplier meshes).


The Boolean modifier works correctly when I use Fast mode instead of Exact, and I'm wondering why. After the "Exact" mode I just select all vertices and apply Merge By Distance.
A attach my BLEND file and the picture:

I'l be glad to understand what I'm doing wrong, and what are the good (right and simple) ways to do that.


Why do you want to use a modifier? Assuming the 'Windows' and main mesh haven't been moved or scaled at all you can just select them both and use Ctrl-J in Object mode to join them. Then in Edit mode select All and hit M > Merge by Distance to get rid of all the overlapping vertices and you'll be back with a single object..

Like John said you can just use ctrl+J and merge them. The reason a boolean is not working is because those objects are non-manifold. You'd have to close the top of the cabin and the window holes. And the windows can't be 2 dimensional planes, they'd need a solidify modifier on them as well.
Booleans usually also have problems if the vertices in both objects overlap perfectly like in this case. You could get around that by scaling the windows individually a bit or remeshing either object

Thanks. I'll be glad not to use a modifier. Yes, I didn't move/scale both obects after separating them from each other. But if I just join them using Ctrl-J, and merge all vertices by distance, then I'll not get a single connected mesh, namely some vertices won't be connected to each other. I just want to return to my single mesh to make new windows with rounded edges.
